# Closing resources created in failed constructor

Tags: oop

Assume I have a class `C` that holds resources that need to be closed as member variables.

```
public class C {
    private ClosableResource1 closableResource1;
    private ClosableResource2 closableResource2;
    .....

    public C(){
        closableResource1 = new ClosableResource1(); 
        closableResource2 = new ClosableResource2(); 
        .....
        // some logic that can fail
    }
    
    close(){
        closableResource1.close()
        closableResource2.close()
        .....
    }
}
```

If the constructor succeeds I can be sure that `close()` will be called eventually by some entity manager and all the resources will be freed.
But how can I make sure I close the resources when the constructor fails? The failure can happen because I have additional logic in the constructor that can throw exception or I get some `RuntimeException` outside of my control?

Some things I though of:

- Wrapping the constructor body with a `try-catch` block. Then, assuming I have a lot of closable members I'll have to have a big `if` statement in the `catch` block checking which resources were already initializing and only close them.
- Offloading the `ClosableResource`s creation to some `init()` function. Then I would have to make sure `init()` succeeded every time I try to use the object.

Is there some elegant solution? Or is this much more implementation specific then that?

Comment: Is there a reason not to use `try-with-resources`? Possibly this is a viable option, when used in your constuctors. Possibly better is to define `init()` functions and call them explicitely after object construction, because then you don't bind resource management to object creation.

Comment: I think it's simply not a good idea to do this. Pass in resources you want to work on, don't mix resource management with its usage.

Comment: @daniu does it still makes sense to pass the resources when they are implementation specific and only relevant to the class that will use them?
Say I have some `FileReader` class, under the hood it manages a Mongo database, so naturally every `FileReader` instance should have access to some Mongo client. Why a user of `FileReader` should even know about Mongo, let alone pass a client to it?

Comment: @Starless You should always avoid *creating* objects in constructor. The point where you're instantiating `C`, you can *try* to instantiate you closeable resources first, and then pass to `C` - avoiding the need to worry about the state of `C` if an error occurs.

Comment: @Starless You can create an intermediate class to create the instance for you without bothering the client, eg a 'FileReaderService` which knows the MongoDB and has a method `createFilereader`, which will return a created reader with the appropriate Mongo instance. The client then only needs to know the service to create objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below:

```
public class C {
    private List<AutoCloseable> closableResources = new ArrayList();
    private ClosableResource1 closableResource1;
    private ClosableResource2 closableResource2;
    .....

    public C() {
        closableResource1 = new ClosableResource1();
        closableResources.add(closableResource1)
        closableResource2 = new ClosableResource2();
        closableResources.add(closableResource2);
        .....
        try {
            // some logic that can fail
        } catch(Exception e) {
            close();
        }
    }
    
    close(){
        for (AutoCloseable closableResource : closableResources) {
            if (closableResource != null) {
                closableResource.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Surrounding your code with try-catch and closing all your resources in catch is the correct solution here. Also read about method finalize() (Here is one [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/object_finalize.htm)). In general, I would recommend one method that cleans up all the resources (like you suggested method `close()`, I would call it though `cleanup()`) and call that method in your catch section and in your `finalize()` method

Answer (score 0):

I asked and answered a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66724036/1235217). It is very important that a constructor either succeeds or fails completely i.e. leaving no resources open. In order to achieve that I would follow each resource creation statement by a try-catch block. The catch block closes the resource and rethrows the exception so it is not lost:

```
  public C() {
    closableResource1 = new ClosableResource1();
    closableResource2 = new ClosableResource2();
    try {
      // .....
      // some logic that can fail and throw MyCheckedException or some RuntimeException
    } catch (RuntimeException | MyCheckedException e) {
      try {closableResource1.close();} catch (Exception ignore) {}
      try {closableResource1.close();} catch (Exception ignore) {}
      throw e;
    }
  }
```

If creating a resource can fail you need nested try-catch blocks as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66724036/1235217).

Comment: This fails if, say, `c1.close()` itself throws an exception.

Comment: True, in that case you can catch and ignore it. I changed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a wild idea: create a class called something like `DefusableCloser` (that you can "defuse", like an explosive device being made safe):

```
class DefusableCloser implements AutoCloseable {
  boolean active = true;
  final AutoCloseable closeable;

  DefusableCloser(AutoCloseable closeable) {
    this.closeable = closeable;
  }

  @Override public void close() throws Exception {
    if (active) closeable.close();
  }
}
```

Now you can use this in a try-with-resources block:

```
c1 = new CloseableResource();
try (DefusableCloseable d1 = new DefusableCloseable(c1)) {
  c2 = new CloseableResource();
  try (DefusableCloseable d2 = new DefusableCloseable(c2)) {
    // Do the other stuff which might fail...

    // Finally, deactivate the closeables.
    d1.active = d2.active = false;
  }
}
```

If execution doesn't reach `d1.active = d2.active = false;`, the two closeables (or one, if the exception was in creating the second resource) will be closed. If execution does reach that line, they won't be closed and you can use them.

The advantage of doing it like this is that the exceptions will be correctly handled.

Note that the ordering is important: don't be tempted to create the two CloseableResources first, then the two DefusableCloseables: doing that won't handle an exception from creating the second CloseableResource. And don't put the creation of the CloseableResources into the TWR, as that would guarantee their closure.

---

For closing the resources in your class' `close()` method, you can also use try-with-resources to ensure that both resources are closed:

```
try (c1; c2) {}
```

You don't actually have to declare a new variable in the TWR syntax: you can just effectively say "close the resource for this existing variable afterwards", as shown here.